# Does lasfilterdecimate work when homogenizing by pulse?

Tags: r, lidar, filter, lidr

In R `lidR` package, when I run `lasfilterdecimate`  with the homogenize option excluding `use_pulse 
 = TRUE` it works, but when I include `use_pulse = TRUE`, it does not work.

For example, the code below does **not** work:

```
currenttilethinned <- lasfilterdecimate(currenttilepulse,homogenize(density,res=20,**use_pulse = TRUE**))
```

The code below works, but I am not sure if it is filtering by pulse (`laspulse` has already been run on the input LAS file, currenttilepulse):

```
currenttilethinned <- lasfilterdecimate(currenttilepulse,homogenize(4.25,res=20))
```

Does homogenize automatically use the pulses when pulseID is present?

Answer (score 1):

I was prompted to have a look closer at the GPS time stamps which the code uses to assign pulse IDs and then thin when `use_pulse=TRUE`. Out of my 5,000+ tiles, it turns out a few tiles had the GPS time stamps removed from the whole tile and thus, wasn't thinning because it only assigned one pulse for the whole tile (4+million points!).

I ended up writing a function that wrote out the number of points, number of pulses for each tile which identified which ones had this problem:

```
CheckPulses <- function(path, density, start_file=1){
  lasfiles <- list.files(path, pattern = "\\.laz$",full.names=TRUE)
  df = data.table(tileID=rep(NA,length(lasfiles)),npoints=NA,npulse=NA)
  for(i in start_file:length(lasfiles)){
    tilename <- basename(lasfiles[i])[[1]]
    currenttile <- readLAS(lasfiles[i])
    currenttilepulse <- laspulse(currenttile)
    df$tileID[i] = tilename
    df$npoints[i] = nrow(currenttile@data)
    df$npulse[i] = length(unique(currenttilepulse@data$pulseID))
  }
  return(df)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for feed back. So everything is ok but it deserves a warning in function `laspulse`.

Comment: @JRR I think a warning would be a great addition! Something to prompt the user that the whole input has only one pulse. Thanks for the prompt communication!